# Cannot run flow in corda node

Tags: corda

I am running a corda network on kubernetes (corda version 4.4) and I am trying to install and run a cordapp .

The cordapp am trying to run is the Heartbeat one (from the github corda sample folder) .

But whenever I try to start the flow using the command `start StartHeartbeatFlow`

I get the following error message :

```sh
[INFO] 11:00:32+0200 [pool-2-thread-11] shell.StartShellCommand.main - Executing command "start StartHeartbeatFlow <no arguments>",
start StartHeartbeatFlow: exception: com.heartbeat.StartHeartbeatFlow
Tue Apr 07 11:00:32 CEST 2020>>> [ERROR] 11:00:32+0200 [pool-2-thread-11] command.CRaSHSession.execute - Error while evaluating request 'start StartHeartbeatFlow' start StartHeartbeatFlow: exception: com.heartbeat.StartHeartbeatFlow [errorCode=1oe81or, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.4/1oe81or]
```

Which doesn't really help me on how to solve the issue :/

Running `flow list` is listing the StartHeartbeatFlow so it's not an issue with the installation of the cordapp ...

Has anyone encountered the same kind of issue ?

Thanks !

Edit : The logs in the corda node I have when I execute the `flow start StartHeartbeatFlow` command .

```sh
corda@corda-node-corda-node-0:~/logs$ tail -f corda-node.log | grep -A 10 -B 10 "heartbeat"
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:09,767Z [Thread-8 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$5@2f4a89fa)] realm.AuthenticatingRealm. - Looked up AuthenticationInfo [rpcuser] from doGetAuthenticationInfo
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:09,767Z [Thread-8 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$5@2f4a89fa)] realm.AuthenticatingRealm. - AuthenticationInfo caching is disabled for info [rpcuser].  Submitted token: [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - rpcuser, rememberMe=false].
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:09,767Z [Thread-8 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$5@2f4a89fa)] credential.SimpleCredentialsMatcher. - Performing credentials equality check for tokenCredentials of type [[C and accountCredentials of type [java.lang.String]
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:09,767Z [Thread-8 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$5@2f4a89fa)] credential.SimpleCredentialsMatcher. - Both credentials arguments can be easily converted to byte arrays.  Performing array equals comparison
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:09,767Z [Thread-8 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$5@2f4a89fa)] authc.AbstractAuthenticator. - Authentication successful for token [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - rpcuser, rememberMe=false].  Returned account [rpcuser]
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:09,768Z [Thread-8 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$5@2f4a89fa)] artemis.BrokerJaasLoginModule. - Login for rpcuser succeeded
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:09,771Z [Thread-12 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] rpc.RPCServer. - -> RPC by rpcuser -> registeredFlows
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:09,772Z [Thread-12 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] rpc.RPCServer. - Arguments: [] {actor_id=rpcuser, actor_owning_identity=OU=Regular Node, O=organization, L=Brussels, C=BE, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=aac88106-cf60-4c63-b1b9-c5fac224b89a, invocation_timestamp=2020-04-07T13:21:09.771Z, origin=rpcuser, session_id=df6cc401-6f9f-41b5-9a18-790c28e33b06, session_timestamp=2020-04-07T13:11:30.204Z}
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:09,772Z [rpc-server-handler-pool-1] realm.AuthorizingRealm. - No authorizationCache instance set.  Checking for a cacheManager... {actor_id=rpcuser, actor_owning_identity=OU=Regular Node, O=organization, L=Brussels, C=BE, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=aac88106-cf60-4c63-b1b9-c5fac224b89a, invocation_timestamp=2020-04-07T13:21:09.771Z, origin=rpcuser, session_id=df6cc401-6f9f-41b5-9a18-790c28e33b06, session_timestamp=2020-04-07T13:11:30.204Z}
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:09,772Z [rpc-server-handler-pool-1] realm.AuthorizingRealm. - No cache or cacheManager properties have been set.  Authorization cache cannot be obtained. {actor_id=rpcuser, actor_owning_identity=OU=Regular Node, O=organization, L=Brussels, C=BE, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=aac88106-cf60-4c63-b1b9-c5fac224b89a, invocation_timestamp=2020-04-07T13:21:09.771Z, origin=rpcuser, session_id=df6cc401-6f9f-41b5-9a18-790c28e33b06, session_timestamp=2020-04-07T13:11:30.204Z}
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:09,773Z [rpc-server-sender] rpc.RPCServer. - <- RPC <- RpcReply(id=10ea96d9-5c19-4200-a64e-1eb3903835ce, timestamp: 2020-04-07T13:21:09.748Z, entityType: Invocation, result=Success([com.heartbeat.StartHeartbeatFlow, net.corda.core.flows.ContractUpgradeFlow$Authorise, net.corda.core.flows.ContractUpgradeFlow$Deauthorise, net.corda.core.flows.ContractUpgradeFlow$Initiate]), deduplicationIdentity=9c974c01-08af-44d0-bdef-c609efee11a8)
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:09,775Z [Thread-62 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$5@2f4a89fa)] artemis.BrokerJaasLoginModule. - Processing login for SystemUsers/NodeRPC
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:09,775Z [Thread-62 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$5@2f4a89fa)] artemis.BrokerJaasLoginModule. - Login for SystemUsers/NodeRPC succeeded
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:09,809Z [Network Map Updater Thread-1] pool.PoolBase. - HikariPool-1 - Reset (autoCommit) on connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@6fa7296c
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:10,560Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.NodeInfoWatcher. - pollDirectory /opt/corda/additional-node-infos
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:10,560Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.NodeInfoWatcher. - Examining /opt/corda/additional-node-infos/nodeInfo-FEBE485DF04D12B91F70740AC3EDDDB1A0C5058B017C6DD6046A1AF37AB1687D
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:10,560Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.NodeInfoWatcher. - Read 0 NodeInfo files from /opt/corda/additional-node-infos
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:10,560Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.NodeInfoWatcher. - Number of removed NodeInfo files 0
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:11,824Z [Network Map Updater Thread-1] pool.PoolBase. - HikariPool-1 - Reset (autoCommit) on connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@6fa7296c
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:13,844Z [Network Map Updater Thread-1] pool.PoolBase. - HikariPool-1 - Reset (autoCommit) on connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@6fa7296c
[DEBUG] 2020-04-07T13:21:15,559Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.NodeInfoWatcher. - pollDirectory /opt/corda/additional-node-infos
```

I could invoke the flow from the standalone shell , I was having some weird issues with the /cordapp folder holding my cordapp locally . I deleted it and recreated it and now it works .

Answer (score 2):

Can you update your question with more stack trace? Are there any other errors in your node's log file? I'm asking because I just tried the example and it worked for me.

Here's what I did:

1. Built the Java version:

```
// Browse to Java files.
cd /heartbeat/contracts-java

// Build the nodes (Notary and PartyA).
./../gradlew deployNodes
```

2. Start the nodes (I don't like using `runnodes` task, so I start each node individually):

```
// Terminal 1 (Notary).

cd /heartbeat/contracts-java/build/nodes/Notary
// Start the Notary.
java -jar corda.jar

// Terminal 2 (PartyA).

cd /heartbeat/contracts-java/build/nodes/PartyA
// Start PartyA.
java -jar corda.jar
```

3. Start the flow inside of PartyA's terminal. Notice that I use `flow start` instead of just `start` (like in your case); it's worth trying `flow start`, even though both should work:

```
flow start StartHeartbeatFlow
```

4. You will see in my screenshot below that the flow completed (i.e. it created the `SchedulableState` that will start the flow again, which will lead to an endless loop until you shutdown the node):

[image: Start Flow]

5. Now I can watch that flow being called again and again by typing the below in PartyA's terminal:

```
flow watch
```

[image: Watch Flow]

Answer (score 0):

I could invoke the flow from the standalone shell , I was having some weird issues with the /cordapp folder holding my cordapp locally . I deleted it and recreated it and now it works .